# Views Exposed Filters do not accept null as 0

Tags: 6, views

I have 4 filters for a travel site that I've made into sliders. They are all supposed to go from 0 to whatever number, but for all of them I also have "Accept NULL as 0" activated.

This seems to be fine if you are only talking about one filter, but it doesn't seem to apply to all of them. I looked at the SQL query that Views puts out and it's only applying the NULL as 0 argument to one of the filters, even though it's activated for all.

I even looked in the database and the null value is on there. Is this a bug, or is there a way to fix this?

I have some objects that have NULL for 3 or even all 4 filters, but I still want them to show up in the list.

Comment: This would be a bugreport to views. One I think I've seen patched somewhere deep in their issue queue, but can't find it now, and Views guys don't seem particularly fast at incorporating user provided patches.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look there and see if I can find it.